# Find all root to leaf paths in binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, interview-questions

**Description:**

Given a binary tree, return all root-to-leaf paths.

[Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/description/)

> ```
> /**
>  * Definition for a binary tree node.
>  * public class TreeNode {
>  *     int val;
>  *     TreeNode left;
>  *     TreeNode right;
>  *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
>  * }
>  */
> ```

**Code:**

```
class Solution {

    public List<String> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode root) {
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        traverse(root, new ArrayList<>(), paths);
        return paths;
    }

    private void traverse(TreeNode root, List<String> path, List<String> paths) {
        if (root == null) return;

        path.add(""+root.val);
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            paths.add(String.join("->", path));
        }

        traverse(root.left,  path, paths);
        traverse(root.right, path, paths);

        path.remove(path.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fine solution.
Tracking the values on the path,
growing and shrinking while traversing to the leafs,
finally adding a concatenated values is natural and easy to understand.

An alternative (and not necessarily better) approach that may perform better is to reduce the string creation, concatenation by replacing the `List<String>` for `path` with a `StringBuilder`, something like:

```
int length = sb.length();
sb.append("->").append(root.val);

if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
    paths.add(sb.substring(2));
}

traverse(root.left,  sb, paths);
traverse(root.right, sb, paths);

sb.setLength(length);
```

This might be premature optimization, and "clever" code.
I think your original is fine as is.

Comment: I thought about it too but went with the generic approach. Also, I am finding this pattern very easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

regarding the translation from `int` to `String`

```
path.add(""+root.val);
```

This is both unclear and also involves unnecessary String creation.  Why not use the "official" conversion method? it clearly states the intention and is more efficient

```
path.add(String.valueOf(root.val));
```